Почему предлагаемые правки были отклонены?
Мне как человеку, которому не хватает репутации для самостоятельных правок (нужна репутация 2K), приходится отправлять свои правки на утверждение.
Да, подавляющую часть правок удаётся подтвердить без проблем, но иногда мои правки отклоняются, и я бы хотел разобраться с тем, почему. Вот мои отклонённые правки (в хронологическом порядке):

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/940400
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/941863
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/941869
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/941964
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/941966
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/942152
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/942513
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/942753
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/942763
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/943038
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/943082
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/943449
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/943719
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/945187
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/945266


Да, это почти все отклонённые правки, но хотелось бы узнать причину их отклонения, а именно — какие допущены ошибки?
Можно ли "отсортировать" предложенные правки по категориям допущенных ошибок, чтобы не допускать эти ошибки в будущем?
А то в пояснении отклонения правки я получаю лишь ничего не значащее сообщение:

Правка не улучшает качество сообщения. Изменения содержимого не являются необходимыми или делают сообщение более запутанным.

Которое мне не помогает разобраться в реальной причине отклонения.


вы использовали цитату вместо обретки кода 3. тоже самое, для кода обратные кавычки 2. ок 1. вы меняете "манеру", зачем то курсивный шрифт ("воду" из вопроса вообще лучше удалять)


@Dev18, видел правки и модераторов, и других участников сообщества с репутацией гораздо выше 2К  — они тоже оформляют текст ошибки в качестве цитаты (да даже мои прочие правки с таким стилем эти же люди принимали, что меня путает ещё больше). По поводу первого — где я поменял манеру общения? Даже если это так, почему тогда не стоило просто убрать курсив и принять правку в целом?

С моей точки зрения: 1 правка - ок, 2 - ок, 3 - не нужно выделять как код, то что кодом не является (название языков программирования, название браузера), 4 - ок. По вопросу - ну, "it" happens. Каждый как-то по-своему решает, что принять, что отклонить.

Про 3, см. Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?

Пожалуйста не надо оборачивать названия в теги предназначенные для кода (Например как  вы сделали в "Ошибка в консоли браузера Firefox"). В остальном годные правки, я бы принял.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/942692 Конструктивная обратная связь важна, но ваши правки кажутся сделанными «ради правок». Пожалуйста, старайтесь глубже вникать в суть того, что вы правите. Например, ссылка, которую вы обернули кодом, на самом деле является изображением, которое автор вопроса просто не смог корректно вставить

@Dev18, мой недочёт по данной правке, при первом рассмотрении считал, что вопрос был в плоскости ссылок. Вот видите, хорошо, что вы это заметили! (А они её приняли, хотя она ухудшает качество )

@Dev18, ваш ответ не стоило удалять, он хороший, а я же не хотел никого обидеть

@Dev18 немного иронично, что эту правку утвердили те же самые участники)

Автокликеры детектед))

@Chaos_Sower да не все одобряют такие правки. Я такие принимаю. Некоторые люди нет.

@Chaos_Sower, я отклоняю правки в основном если они выглядят слишком косметическими, см. мой подобный вопрос на мете.  Правки, указанные в вопросе, в основном были связаны с избыточным (по-моему)  форматированием или незначительными огрехами (пунктуацией, игнорированием прописных букв и т.п.), потому и были отклонены.  Правка про "крошки" показалась существенной прежде всего из-за коррекции текста в заголовке, я посмотрел историю -- я принимал её дважды.  Автокликером не пользуюсь, спасибо.

теперь, после создания вами этого вопроса, ваши правки  принимаются (в поддержку вам), но советую обращать внимание на историю ПЕРЕправок, чтоб смотреть, что за вами ПЕРЕправляют https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1390452/revisions //как например вы удалили тег html, который имеет все таки отношение к вопросу

А они её приняли, хотя она ухудшает качество ... => посмотрев правку, я сразу поняла. почему именно ее приняли. Вы указали Исправление заголовка на более подходящий + форматирование => что достаточно весомо, тк заголовок играет ключевую роль, дальше доверившись вам не стали проверять код или не код вы обернули. Я не стала отвечать это все ДО ответа самого проверяющего, но его комментарий только поддтвердил мою гипотезу. То есть, здесь главное понимать, что к счастью мы пока не роботы, и каждый может ошибаться, главная наша задача работать сообща. Это и создает сообщество...

@Dev18, слишком всё затягивается) Есть у каждого правки-"браки" (как в моём случае), есть и проверки-"браки" (как в этом случае). Вот теперь думаю, менять ли содержимое вопроса, абстрогировав его от конкретных людей... Не устану повторять, что ваш ответ был хороший и полезный, вы зря его удадлили (но право ваше). Вы правы, все мы люди, и поэтому поступать нужно по-человечески. Сам вопрос поднял потому, что в некоторых случаях, когда тратишь на внимательную правку 20 и более минут, свои силы, вчитываясь в содержимое — становится обидно, что труды... не принимаются, если можно так сказать

Хм, нормальные правки. Странно...

Итак, пора закрыть это "гештальт". Попробую самостоятельно ответить на вопрос.

Вы указали почти все свои отклонённые правки. На подробный вопрос будет подробный ответ. Кроме вас с вашими правками на столь детальном уровне никто ознакамливаться не будет (но я попробую).

О какой "дискриминации" правок может идти речь, когда у вас на данный момент 316 принятых, 30 отклонённых и 2 отменённые правки? Коэффициент принятых правок 316 / 348, что составляет > 90 % от всех предложенных правок. Дискриминации тут не вижу.

Посмотрите на некоторые свои правки, которые не назовёшь "корректными":



https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/942941 — удалили метку html, а она не лишняя
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/942753 — присмотритесь, вы удалили символ " в коде
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/945177 — "исправили" метку xml на xaml, а должна быть именно метка xml (но вы её потом вернули, что хорошо)


Что из этого следует?
Все мы люди, и все мы ошибаемся. Фактор человеческой ошибки никто не отменял, поэтому:

Старайтесь вносить явное описание правки, чтобы проверяющий понимал её назначение.

Старайтесь делать меньше "правок ради правок" (AKA замена е → ё, Application.cs → Application.cs и т. д.) по типу таких:



https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/941863
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/942152
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/943719


Важное замечание
Исправление табуляции в коде, пунктуаций и ошибок в правописании текста, а также изменение заголовка на более понятный, на мой взгляд, более, чем хорошая цель правки, поэтому нужно сосредоточиться на создании именно таких правок.
"Правками ради правок" можете заняться при достижении репутации в 2 000 очков, тогда вам уже никто не запретит вносить незначительные правки, которые ничего не меняют (но так вы сможете утолить свою жажду сделать правку ).
Главное ни в коем случае не забывать, что:

Правка не должна искажать суть изначального сообщения (удаление символа или буквы в коде могут его кардинально поменять) — к этому нужно подходить серьёзно.
Из сообщения не должны удаляться детали, которые дополняют основную мысль сообщения.
Не нужно пытаться "расшифровать" то, что имел в виду автор (по типу "У меня структура классов не юзается, что делать?" — вот что имел в виду автор вопроса? Непонятно, это не трогаем и не меняем, автор сам должен исправить этот текст и/или внести ясность).

Про правки, касающихся перевода сообщений, — хорошая дискуссия тут.

По поводу остальных правок — почему их отклонили я не знаю.
Вот это я вообще не могу объяснить:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/943449
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1334051/revisions
Но я хотя бы в первый раз увидел опцию, которую до этого никогда не видел — "Отклонить и править". Так что хоть что-то новое узнали)) Видимо, правка настолько понравилась проверяющему, что её решили забрать (вам что, жалко что ли?)) ).

Но я особо хочу выделить данную вашу правку:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/942428
Она отклонена проверяющими, но принята автором. В таких случаях такие правки принимаются с шансом 50/50. Автор принял правку, а это самое главное. Почему вопрос не переоткрыли после правки, а решили отклонить её — кто знает ¯_(ツ)_/¯, это уже тема для отдельного вопроса.

Если вы всё же считаете нужным добиться принятия правки — просто попробуйте её отправить на проверку повторно. Вижу, что вы так и поступали, и, насколько мне известно, это сработало в большинстве случаев.
Если же вашу правку забракуют повторно, то стоит задуматься о том, что что-то с ней может быть не так.

По поводу отклонённых правок от самих авторов (в вашем вопросе они не указаны):

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/940401
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/941839
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/943707
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/944379

Тут вы мало что сможете сделать — на то их воля. Разве только вы потом попробуете снова применить правку уже самостоятельно. Но важно уважать мнение автора, даже если вам это и не особо нравится.

Про правила оформления правок дана нужная информация тут.
Как-то так 

P. S. Спасибо пользователям за обратную связь в комментариях под вопросом!
P. P. S. Отдельная благодарность за обратную связь @Dev18 и @insolor — без них было бы труднее разобраться в данном вопросе!

правка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/943449 была отклонена, поскольку она была слишком формальной, в частности, не были исправлены очевидные опечатки в английском тексте сообщения, которые отсутствуют на скриншоте.

@NowhereMan, да, теперь увидел, спасибо за пояснения! Но я всё ещё не понимаю, в чём отличие между "Принять и править" и "Отклонить и править")) Опцию выбирает сам проверяющий?

Да, опцию выбирает проверяющий, на своё усмотрение.  Чтобы выбрать "Отклонить и править", предложенная правка должна быть явно недостаточной или вносить какие-то дополнительные проблемы, к примеру, грамматические ошибки или непоследовательное форматирование. По моей приблизительной статистике "отклонить и править" выбирается очень редко, меньше чем в 1% случаев, "Принять и править" -- немногим чаще (около 2-2,5%).
